# Firrtl parser syntax errors for custom Record type

Tags: scala, chisel

I have a custom Record type which represents a matrix. The Record.elements value contains the entries of the matrix is indexed with a key string which consists of the row number, an underscore, and the column number; i.e. s"${row}_${col}".

I also have a second custom Record type which represents an array of matrices, which do not all have to be the same size (which is why I can't use Vec). For this type, Record.elements contains the matrices and is simply indexed with an int, similar to other array types.

Something is causing the Firrtl parser to barf up syntax errors, which look like this:

```
line 8:30 no viable alternative at input '_0@[Matrix.scala 53:19]'
```

and this:

```
line 376:22 no viable alternative at input 'MatMul_1.io.in.1.3_0'
```

Some quick searching seems to indicate that this error is bubbling up from ANTLR, but at this point I concede that I am out of my depth.

Here is the stack trace, not including user code

```
Exception in thread "main" firrtl.SyntaxErrorsException: 77 syntax error(s) detected
at firrtl.Parser$$anonfun$1.apply(Parser.scala:45)
at firrtl.Parser$$anonfun$1.apply(Parser.scala:33)
at firrtl.Utils$.time(Utils.scala:182)
at firrtl.Parser$.parseCharStream(Parser.scala:33)
at firrtl.Parser$.parseString(Parser.scala:29)
at firrtl.Driver$$anonfun$getCircuit$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Driver.scala:172)
at firrtl.Driver$$anonfun$getCircuit$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Driver.scala:172)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at firrtl.Driver$$anonfun$getCircuit$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Driver.scala:172)
at firrtl.Driver$$anonfun$getCircuit$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Driver.scala:172)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at firrtl.Driver$$anonfun$getCircuit$1.apply(Driver.scala:171)
at firrtl.Driver$$anonfun$getCircuit$1.apply(Driver.scala:160)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at firrtl.Driver$.getCircuit(Driver.scala:160)
at firrtl.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:212)
at firrtl.Driver$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Driver.scala:209)
at logger.Logger$$anonfun$makeScope$1.apply(Logger.scala:129)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at logger.Logger$.makeScope(Logger.scala:127)
at firrtl.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:209)
at chisel3.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:182)
at chisel3.Driver$.execute(Driver.scala:202)
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some head scratching, I figured it out: the Firrtl grammar (like many others) places restrictions on variable and field identifiers: they cannot begin with a number. Since the keys of my custom Record types all began with numbers, and Chisel uses the Record keys directly as Firrtl identifiers, the Firrtl parser was reporting the error.

tl;dr The keys that you use to index your custom Record.elements must be valid Firrtl identifiers (e.g. they cannot begin with a numeric).

Comment: Nice work figuring this out. Would you mind filing it as an issue on the FIRRTL repo since this is definitely a bug? https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/issues

Comment: Are you using Chisel/FIRRTL from the published versions or are you building them from source? I don't think it's in the releases yet (slated for 3.2.0/1.2.0) but we are now largely using Protobuf instead of the parser which should not suffer from this issue

Comment: I was using the published version 3.1.3. I will create an issue to track this: thanks for the response! Edit: is this truly an issue with Firrtl? I thought it might be Chisel's problem, in that Chisel should error if you try to define a Record key using an invalid Firrtl identifier.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure. We allow digits as identifiers (in fields at least) so I see no reason why we shouldn't allow `\d_\d`

Comment: As far as I can tell, Firrtl doesn't allow digits to begin identifiers at all. From the Firrtl spec version 0.2.0: _"The following characters are allowed in identifiers: upper and lower case letters, digits, and _. Identifiers cannot begin with a digit."_